# Applying linear gradient to border using percentage

Tags: css, sass, border, linear-gradients, figma

I know that for applying a linear gradient, we need at-least 2 colours. But this is what i see in figma from the designer. How do i translate this into css. And the `#4D00F0` is a dynamic colour in my case. How do i apply gradient with a dynamic colour as border .Please help. The end result should look like this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: that's a radial-gradient not a linear one

Comment: You mean the one applied on the border? I know that the inner background is a radial one. how about the one on border?